# Passing the type of exception to be caught

Tags: java, exception, testing

I'm building a little testing framework for my own code, and I'd like to be able to do this:

```
test.callTo(() -> {/*...*/}).doesThrow(SomeException.class);
```

or something like that.

The `callTo` method would just build an instance of a class which holds a `java.lang.Runnable` (or similar). That class will have a `doesThrow` method, which takes ***some parameter*** which represents the type of exception to be caught, and does this:

```
try {
    try {
        method.run();
    } catch(ThePassedInExceptionType e) {
        /* test passed */
        return;
    }
} catch (Throwable e) {}
/* test failed */
```

Is this type of thing possible? If so, how can it be done, and if not, what else could I do to ensure that my code throws the correct exceptions short of doing try/catch in my test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is pass a `Class<? extends Exception>`. Call this parameter `clazz`.

Then you could do

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (clazz.isInstance(e)) 
        // do something
}
```

I'm not sure if this is good practice, but it should work.

Comment: Dammit, Paul, you were 3 seconds quicker :)

Comment: Lol I don't know which one to accept. You guys gave the same answer 3 seconds apart. I guess Andy gets it for **technically** being first.

Comment: @AndyTurner It happens to us all, but 3 seconds is pretty annoying.

Comment: @anthropomorphic to be clear, Paul posted his answer 3 seconds before me.

Comment: Really? My browser said the opposite. Weird.

Comment: Would it be better to do `? extends Exception` or `? extends Throwable`?

Comment: Probably `Throwable`. I was too busy writing a speedy answer to give the most general answer. I won't be offended if you accept the other answer as it gives full details of catch block

Comment: Yes, but then your answer also includes the type to be passed.

Comment: @anthropomorphic I usually flip a coin in these situations!

Comment: `isInstance()` doesn't seem to exist for either `Exception` or `Throwable`

Comment: Oh derp I did it backwards (ie. `e.isInstance(clazz)` instead of `clazz.isInstance(e)`)

Comment: `isInstance` is badly named, so it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it directly, since the exception handling table is built at compile-time, and you don't know the expected exception type then.

However, you can probably do something like this, using reflection:

```
try {
  method.run();
} catch (Throwable t) {
  if (exceptionClass.isInstance(t)) {
    return; /* test passed */
  }
  throw t;  /* test failed; propagate error */
}
```